# Display custom post type archive page as homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

The code I have is in my functions.php file and is displaying the custom post type 'events' posts as needed, but not sorting by the meta value 'upcoming_date'. It is not sorting in ascending order either. Moreover, is it possible to sort by 2 metavalues? Please help.

```
add_action("pre_get_posts", "cpt_front_page");
function cpt_front_page( $wp_query ){

    //Ensure this filter isn't applied to the admin area
    if(is_admin()) {
        return;
    }

    if($wp_query->get('page_id') == get_option('page_on_front')):

        $wp_query->set( 'post_type', 'events' );
        $wp_query->set( 'page_id', '' ); //Empty

        //Set properties that describe the page to reflect that
        //we aren't really displaying a static page     
        $wp_query->is_page = 0;
        $wp_query->is_singular = 0;
        $wp_query->is_post_type_archive = 1;
        $wp_query->is_archive = 1;

        //sort the posts by meta value in ascending order       
        $wp_query->meta_key = 'upcoming_date'; // <= IS THIS RIGHT?
        $wp_query->orderby = 'meta_value'; // <= IS THIS RIGHT?
        $wp_query->order = 'ASC'; // <= IS THIS RIGHT?

    endif;

}
```

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100473/ordering-wordpress-posts-with-meta-values

Comment: Thank you for the answer, how would be the implement in the code I have? ie:`$wp_query->order = 'ASC';` is not doing it...

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely an issue with how you're storing your upcoming date and attempting to sort with it. You'll probably get the best chance of success by storing your dates in `yymmdd` format, and setting `orderby` to `'meta_value_num'`, so that it sorts in a numerical order rather than a textual order.

```
$wp_query->meta_key = 'upcoming_date';
$wp_query->orderby = 'meta_value_num';
$wp_query->order = 'ASC';
```

The [documentation on orderby](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) is a good reference.